# TabItem OnSelectionChanged() setting focus on inner control (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two `TabItem`'s contained inside a `TabControl`.

Each `TabItem` contains serveral `TextBox`'s.

When `TabControl`'s `OnSelectionChanged` event is fired, as well as selecting the new `TabItem`, it is also setting focus on the first `TextBox` contained inside the newly selected item.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Setting `IsTabStop="False"` on the `TextBox` will achieve this, but unfortunately  also prevents the `TextBox` from being 'tabbed' into.

Comment: I would recommend setting focus to a label or some other non input control, on tab selection changed.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder thanks for the idea. Although that didn't work, `<TextBox Width="0" MinWidth="0" MaxWidth="0"></TextBox>` did - although it feels a bit hacky!

Answer (score 2):

In your tab control, handle the focus event for each of the tabs like this:

```
<TabItem GotFocus="TabItem_OnGotFocus">
```

Then just remove focus using:

```
private void TabItem_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Keyboard.ClearFocus();
}
```

Comment: Any alterlative available now? This solved the problem but discrupt the MVVM structure.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a container to your content as Grid, Stackpanel, Border, etc. and set it Focusable. When Tab selection change, the focus is set to the container and you can also use the tab key.

```
<TabItem Header="myHeader">
    <StackPanel Focusable="True">
       ...    
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

@shannon it answers to your question about MVVM